# How can I delete all data from multiple Baqend tables?

Tags: javascript, database, angular, baqend

I need to delete all rows from multiple tables, programmatically (not in the dashboard). Is there an API for that? I couldn't find it in the [documentation](https://www.baqend.com/guide/?_ga=1.109326405.1797973939.1466098109).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this is currently not documented. You can however find the REST call in our [API Explorer](https://dashboard.global.ssl.fastly.net/swagger-ui/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftoodle-bq.global.ssl.fastly.net%2Fv1%2Fspec) although you don't get the syntactic sugar from the JS SDK. The REST call is a `DELETE` to `/db/{bucket}` where `bucket` is the name of the Table to delete. With the JS SDK this request is wrapped into a message object `TruncateBucket`, you can use it like this:

```
    DB.login("userWithAdminRole", "<password>").then(function() {
        return DB.send(new DB.message.TruncateBucket('<table>'));
    }).then(function () {
        console.log('truncated!');
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log('catch truncated!');
    });
```

> Note: If you are calling this code from your frontend you need the
>   admin role (hence the `DB.login`). If you are calling the code from a
>   backend module (where you always have the `node` role) you can skip
>   the login.

---

You can also try out all REST request in the [API Explorer](https://dashboard.global.ssl.fastly.net/swagger-ui/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftoodle-bq.global.ssl.fastly.net%2Fv1%2Fspec). It looks like this:

[image: API Explorer]